# Load values from WEB before MainActivity start

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My app have Search filed with autocomplete.

Now I have these:

1) AsyncTask class that loads Dictionary and save it in file to InternalStorage (I need it to use preloaded items in case when network unavailable).

2) Application class with overrided onCreate Method. Here I executing AsyncTask (1).

The problem is that MainActivity with Search filed starts before AsyncTask finished, so autocomplete loaded NOT relevant (old) dictionary.

I need to complete my AsyncTask **no earlier than** MainActivity loads dictionary file from Internal Storage.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks for Answers.

upd: Okay, there is code:

```
package com.XXX.XXX.app;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        if (CheckNetworkConnect.check(MyApp.this)) {
            LoadData getData = new LoadData(MyApp.this);
            getData.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

After that I load file **in MainActivity** class from Internal Storage with my own InternalStorage class.

```
try {
        acList = (ArrayList<String>) InternalStorage.readObject(MainActivity.this, "aclist");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        acList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("NO FILE"));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And then applying getted ArrayList to dropdown

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.dropdown_item, acList);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.searchFiled);
    searchFiled.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: could you please the relevant code please ?

Comment: do this in an activity, call it splashScreen or something, when asyncTask finish, start the mainActivity. how about that?

Comment: @Yazan it's a good idea, but it would be better to do without Splash Screen. Or make SplashScreen appeared only if network is available. And if there is no network - immediately start MainActivity, without SplashScreen. And if I did it that way - how can I handle that AsyncTask finished?

Comment: @udenfox yes splash could appear only if connection is available. you can add a boolean flag IS_DOWNLOADING, and check it at main activity when user start a search, you can show a message or toast, "Updating data..." until the flag changes `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have many choice, you have to wait for your task to be finished. Otherwise, as you mentioned it, old, not relevant, data will be used.

1. You can wait for your task to be finished in your activity, with a ProgressDialog maybe, using `theTask.get()` or check its status `theTask.getStatus()` (the task will have to have visibility from the activity)
2. You can launch the task in your activity, also with a progressDialog, and fill `acList` in the OnPostExecute part
3. You can make a splash screen activity, which role will be to load data, as soon as it's finished, MainActivity will be launched

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you could load the Dictionary in MainActivity onCreate, before setting up the search field. Or you could wait for the AsyncTask to end by calling AsyncTaskClass.execute().get(), check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Comment: Thanks! This is solution.